# TSQL to tell which network protocol is being used for each active session

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Once upon a time, I remember running some TSQL which would display which network protocol (e.g. named pipes, TCP/IP) was being used by each active session - but I can't remember the actual code. Does anyone know how to do this ? An input parameter might have been SPID. The code was useful for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+ [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) has "net_transport" column

[sysprocesses](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx) has a `net_library` column valid for older SQL Server too

So, a `SELECT net_library FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE SPID = 123 /* use @@SPID for current connection */` will give you this info.